# Fill checkbox array names from strings

Tags: c#, arrays, string, checkbox

I'm trying to fill a checkbox array with checkbox names derived from strings. I would like to replace the following code:

```
    public void CheckBox_1()
    {
        CheckBox[] boxes_1 = new CheckBox[4];

        boxes_1[0] = A0;
        boxes_1[1] = A1;
        boxes_1[2] = A2;
        boxes_1[3] = A3;

        for (int i = 0;i < 4;i++)   
        {
            boxes_1[i].Enabled = checkBox1.Checked == true ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

with something like this:

```
    public void CheckBox_1()
    {
        CheckBox[] boxes_1 = new CheckBox[4];

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            boxes_1[i] = ("A" + i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            boxes_1[i].Enabled = checkBox1.Checked == true ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

I can get the checkbox name to a string easy enough, but it's not clear how to accomplish this. Thanks.

Comment: putting the checkboxes in a list would be better.  The way you're doing it will require reflection.

Comment: You could use reflection.... but you should clarify about your final goal. Maybe we'll be able to provide a better way to do the job.

Comment: Are the related checkboxes somehow grouped together (f.e. GroupBox)?

Comment: "boxes_1[i].Enabled = checkBox1.Checked == true ? true : false;" So if true is true return true... alternatively if false is not true return false?  Any reason for the ternary if?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Control.Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) of the containing object to get all the `CheckBox` controls via `OfType<T>` and then filter on the `Name`s that start with "A".

```
var container = ...control with the checkboxes...;

foreach(var cb in container.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("A")))
{
   cb.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fiddling around with reflection just to create code that is prone to errors and difficult to understand, i would suggest to group the related checkboxes in container controls like `GroupBox`.

Then it's very easy and readable:

```
// consider renaming
public void CheckBox_1()
{
    var relatedCheckBoxes = GroupBox1.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
    foreach (var chk in relatedCheckBoxes)
        chk.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked; // you might want to pass this checkbox as argument instead
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that checkboxes could be nested inside other controls inside of some common container, this might work:

```
    private void CheckBox_1()
    {
        foreach (var checkbox in FindChildren<CheckBox>(container, c => c.Name.StartsWith("A")))
        {
            checkbox.Enabled = checkBox1.Checked == true ? true : false;
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> FindChildren<T>(Control parent, Func<T, bool> filter)
        where T : Control
    {
        var search = new Stack<Control>();
        search.Push(parent);

        while (search.Count > 0)
        {
            parent = search.Pop();

            foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
            {
                T typed = child as T;

                if (typed != null && filter(typed))
                {
                    yield return typed;
                    continue;
                }

                search.Push(child);
            }
        }
    }
```